# Провести корреляцию между двумя матрицами

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, матрицы

Есть две матрицы 300 на 300 элементов.
По оси Y название программы, по оси X их версии.
Как правильно провести корреляцию между ними и какие инструменты python можно использовать.
Я пробовала множественную линейную регрессию, но она сюда не очень подходит.
Какие есть еще варианты помимо регрессии.

Примеры матриц.

Матрица 1:

```
        Version1 Version2 Version3
Program1 0.7865   0.6438   0.5323
Program2 0.0235   0.6327   0.7324
Program3 0.0843   0.5362   0.7533
```

Матрица 2:

```
            Version1 Version2 Version3
    Program1 0.5656   0.8534   0.9246
    Program2 0.0325   0.8424   0.8265
    Program3 0.6391   0.2567   0.1577
```

Для примера я взяла размером 3 на 3, суть в том что мне нужно найти корреляцию между данными этих двух матриц

Comment: Между кем "ними" вы хотите найти корреляцию? Между версими программ? А регрессию? Что в регрессии независимая переменная, а что - зависимая?

Comment: Да, между версиями программ. Регрессия сюда не подошла именно по этой причине, потому что нельзя определить зависимую и независимую переменную

Comment: Покажите хотя бы пример ваших данных, так ничего непонятно. И как звучит исходная задача, а то мне кажется вы не ту задачу решаете, которая у вас есть.

Comment: Добавила примеры

Comment: И всё-таки корреляция ищется между двумя рядами чисел. Вы хотите найти корреляцию между одинаковыми версиями в двух матрицах? Ну, тогда перебирайте столбцы, берите один и тот же столбец из матрицы1 и матрицы2 и считайте коэффициент корреляции. Либо со строками тоже самое, если корреляция нужна между одной программой в разных матрицах. А методов считать корреляции есть миллион разных: https://realpython.com/numpy-scipy-pandas-correlation-python/

Comment: Просто мне всё-равно непонятен смысл того, что вы делаете. Зачем это, с какой целью?

Comment: Задача в том чтобы найти зависимость между двумя разными матрицами данных , чтобы понять как одни влияют на другие. Если что, я это не сама придумала)

Comment: Так вы хотите найти корреляцию между - например -  значениями столбца Version1 в первой матрице и значением столбца Version1 во второй матрице? И данные у вам просто вещественные числа в диапазоне от 0 до 1? Тогда чем вам не подошел элементарный коэффициент корреляции Пирсона? Про какую "зависимую" и "независимую" переменную вы говорите  -  стало еще менее понятно, чем было в начале. Все-таки хотите квалифицированной помощи -  семантику задачи опишите. А то, что "вы не сами придумали"  -  вполне верю. Но эту задачу мы видим пока что в вашей интерпретации, и не факт, что корректной.